# forcing silex framework to generate https links

Tags: php, symfony, https, routes, silex

My entire application should be accessed over HTTPS,
The vhost is correctly configured and when I call any of my application pages with the HTTPS prefix, it responds correctly.

However when I try to access a page through a generated link within my application. it always points to a regular HTTP link.

I first tried to redirect all traffic to HTTPS using .htaccess file. Spent a few hours trying every redirect method I could find on the net but I always ended up having a infinite redirect loop for some reason.

Now I'm trying to approach this in a different way: generating directly my links in HTTPS. All my links are generated using the `URL()` function provided by twig-bridge.

It is pretty easy to configure with  [Symfony](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/routing/scheme.html)

But I couldnt figure out how to do it with Silex. Is there an easy way to change the routing scheme in Silex to force every link to be generated with an HTTPS prefix ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding `requireHttps()` to your routes generator, would do the trick.

Example:

```
$app->get('/hello-world', function($app) {
    return 'Hello world';
})
->bind('hello') // Set route name (optional of course)
->requireHttps(); // This would force your url with https://
```

You can look at the [API](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/api/Silex/Route.html) as well for more information. You will find everything you need there.

Comment: nice one, it seems to be the proper way to do it. However it triggers the same redirect loop I was getting when I tried to do it using the .htaccess file. Which probably means something must be wrong in the vhost configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Set environment variable `HTTPS` to `on`.

Nginx config inside location: `fastcgi_param HTTPS on;`
Apache's .htaccess or vhost config: `SetEnv HTTPS on`

Note that default nginx config in official docs sets this variable to `off` which may be copypasted to https sites and it's wrong:
http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/web_servers.html
Ctrl+F - `fastcgi_param HTTPS off;`

Answer (score 1):

In case your using the [Controller Providers](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.0/providers.html#controller-providers), you can use the [`requireHttps()`](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/api/master/Silex/Controller.html#method_requireHttps) method from `Controller` class to require HTTPS for the entire scope of routes:

```
namespace Acme;

use Silex\Application;
use Silex\Api\ControllerProviderInterface;

class HelloControllerProvider implements ControllerProviderInterface
{
    public function connect(Application $app)
    {
        $controllers = $app['controllers_factory'];
        $controllers->get('/', function (Application $app) {
            return $app->redirect('/hello');
        });
        $controllers->get('/another-page', 'Acme\HelloControllerProvider::doSomething')->bind('another-page');
        // here it goes
        $controllers->requireHttps();
        // or even make it more flexible with a config variable
        // if ($app['config']['require_https']) (
        //     $controllers->requireHttps();
        // }
        return $controllers;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For that specific case, I solved the problem declaring a base url like so in app.php:

```
$app['customBaseUrl'] = 'https://mybaseurl';
```

then prefixed all my links with this custom baseUrl. Those links aren't generated by the url() twig function anymore.

Not the prettiest way to do it though. I would recommend Artamiel's answer if your server configuration allows you to use it.

Comment: Then that means you figured out what went wrong about those loops? If your application works fine with this, then technically it should work with url generator as well.

Comment: For some reason, adding ->requireHttps(); produced the same result I had with the the redirection in the .htaccess file.

I figured something was wrong in the configuration of the vhost, I don't know exactly what since I didn't have the rights to access it. And the hosting company takes a fair amount of time to deal with those issues.
 
I had to find a quick fix and this did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use the access_control in the SecurityServiceProvider setup (if you are using this) to specify that certain routes require the use of https by specifying the
'requires_channel' => 'https' in the access_control part of the security configuration.